# Encrypt/Decrypt Plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, plist

OK, so here's what I need :

- I have a (rather big) binary .plist associated with my app, containing info that I wouldn't really like it if a user would access it and view the contents (as would normally happen with a regular un-encrypted plist file, binary-or-not).
- I want to encrypt the .plist (using a pass)
- Include the encrypted .plist in my app bundle
- Decrypt the .plist at app launch

How would you go about it? Is there any built-in way to make it easier for me to achieve that?

---

*P.S. I don't think it'll make much of a difference, but I'm interested in a working OSX solution, **not** an iOS one*

Comment: Could you provide a bit more insight into the nature of the .plist? Is it just a static file that ships built into the product's resources? Does it NEED to be a .plist (i.e. could the contents just be baked right into the binary as an NSDictionary)? And does it have to be specifically password-protected, or just secure and hidden from user access? I can probably help with a solution, but I need to know a little more about what's going on.